# Missing crt0.o file with cross-i386 gcc

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, crt, newlib

I can't find out why crt0.o or crt1.o are not provided for i386 targets by newlib as it is the case for powerpc, arm, etc. targets.

ld requires it (and so do I to call static constructors).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the rationale behind removing crt0.o from gcc4-7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981704/what-is-the-rationale-behind-removing-crt0-o-from-gcc4-7-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question directly asked on newlib's mailing list:
http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/Question-i386-s-crt0-tp229290p229999.html