# How to resolve crt0.o linking issue in cross compiling?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi, crt

How to add `ctr0.o` ?

I get this error:

```
yagarto-4.7.2/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

while compiling very simple program from [here](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/09/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-1/):

```
/* -- first.s */
/* This is a comment */
.global main /* 'main' is our entry point and must be global */
.func main   /* 'main' is a function */

main:          /* This is main */
    mov r0, #2 /* Put a 2 inside the register r0 */
    bx lr      /* Return from main */
```

I have seen these 2 threads and didn't get any full and straight forward answer:

1. http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=50046
2. [What is the rationale behind removing crt0.o from gcc4.7.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981704/what-is-the-rationale-behind-removing-crt0-o-from-gcc4-7-x)

I have these files, what is the difference between crt0 and crtn can't I use it?

```
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/crtbegin.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/crtend.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/crti.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/crtn.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/crtbegin.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/crtend.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/crti.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/crtn.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v6m/crtbegin.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v6m/crtend.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v6m/crti.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v6m/crtn.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v7m/crtbegin.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v7m/crtend.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v7m/crti.o
./yagarto-4.7.2/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/thumb/v7m/crtn.o
```

The SO solution gives a workaround which doesn't work either:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o first assembler_tutorial/chapter01/first.o -nostartfiles
./yagarto-4.7.2/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

vectors.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl main
hang: b hang
```

main.s

```
.globl main
main:
    mov r0,#2
    bx lr
```

memmap (linker script)

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

commands

```
arm-none-eabi-as vectors.s -o vectors.o
arm-none-eabi-as main.s -o main.o
arm-none-eabi-ld vectors.o main.o -T memmap -o main.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D main.elf > main.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy main.elf -O binary main.bin
```

result

```
main.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000000    bl  800c <main>

00008008 <hang>:
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <hang>

0000800c <main>:
    800c:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

If you want to use C instead of asm for main then

main.c

```
int main ( void )
{
    return(2);
}
```

commands

```
arm-none-eabi-as vectors.s -o vectors.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -c main.c -o main.o
arm-none-eabi-ld vectors.o main.o -T memmap -o main.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D main.elf > main.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy main.elf -O binary main.bin
```

result

```
main.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000000    bl  800c <main>

00008008 <hang>:
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <hang>

0000800c <main>:
    800c:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

I prefer to use a function name other than main because some compilers add extra baggage when they see that function name.

vectors.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl notmain
hang: b hang
```

main.c

```
int notmain ( void )
{
    return(2);
}
```

result

```
main.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000000    bl  800c <notmain>

00008008 <hang>:
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <hang>

0000800c <notmain>:
    800c:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Comment: You have to be careful getting rid of crt0, you have to replace that functionality in some way (replace it or knowingly do without).  I have more bare metal raspberry pi examples at http://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi

Comment: An extremely helpful answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with trying to compile for STM32F4xx (Cortex M4).

I ditched Yagarto and switched to using GNU Tools ARM Embedded - 
toolchain (4.8_2014q2):

https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

Seems to work for me.